# .subscribe method is returning undefined in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rxjs, ionic4

The **method** in my **webservice class return **dat**a** but when I try to access the **data** by **.subscribe** method in my **component** it returns **undefined**.

The code of method in my **service class**. **I am getting data in this method**. And I can **see it using console.log**.

```
getData() {
return this.networkService
  .getRequest("clienti/v1/session")
  .pipe(
    map(
      (data) => {
        console.log("getData");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
       
          return data;
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("getData error");
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  );
 }
```

The code in my **component** class, I am **getting undefined here in console.log**:

```
recoverData() {

this.dataService.getData().subscribe(
  (data) => {
    console.log("data");
    console.log(data);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  }
);
}
```

If someone knows what is the problem then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're aren't using the `map` operator to transform the notification, you could use [`tap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap) operator instead. It also accepts the error callback like you're attempting to do. In contrast, the [`map`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) operator **does not** accept the error callback function, so the error logs won't be printed.

Try the following

```js
getData() {
  return this.networkService.getRequest("clienti/v1/session").pipe(
    tap(
      (data) => {
        console.log("getData");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log("getData error");
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
  );
}
```

The `tap` only performs side-effects (like the console logs here) and doesn't require any value to be returned.